# Kronecker product for matrices over noncommutative fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, kronecker-product

Suppose $A, B, C, D$ are matrices over a commutative field such that $AC$ and $BD$ are well defined. Then we know that

$$(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) = (AC) \otimes (BD).$$

Are there clean formulas available over noncommutative fields (starting from the left-hand side) ?

Comment: I started with commenting that it was always true (which is the case in my interpretation), but actually the real question is "what do you mean by $A\otimes B$"?

Comment: @CaptainLama : the Kronecker product between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Boccherini this formula still holds for non-commutative fields.  It suffices to note that we have $(A \otimes B)(v \otimes w) = (Av) \otimes (Bw)$ for column vectors $v,w$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No. For instance if all four of $A,B,C,D$ are $1\times 1$ quaternionic matrices, the Kronecker product is just the product, and then the formula would read $abcd=acbd$.

Comment: @runway44 you're right; thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I suspect that if the entries of $B$ and $C$ are all in the center of the skew field, then the identity holds as is

Comment: My stance on this is that I don't see any reason why anyone would ever use the naive definition of the Kronecker product over non-commutative rings. It does not have any useful interpretation that I can see. On the other hand the formula in the question is valid over arbitrary rings for a correct interpretation of the tensor product (possibly over $\mathbb{Z}$, possibly over the center, basically over anything commutative).

Comment: @CaptainLama : could you explain what the correct interpretation of the tensor product for matrices over arbitrary rings is ? (What is the definition ?)

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental problems going on here:

1. Over a noncommutative ring, one cannot take a tensor product of two right modules, and
2. Over a noncommutative ring, the space of linear maps is *not* a module over the original ring.

The first problem is fairly obvious when you try to do it, you really need to be taking a tensor product of a left module with a right module to impose the equivariance condition. I find the second problem more interesting, since a bunch of stuff that you would otherwise think is meaningful (writing down diagonal scalar matrices for instance) seems to go horrifically wrong in the noncommutative case.

Let $R$ be a unital ring, not necessarily commutative. Then obviously we can form matrices with entries in $R$, and we still have matrix addition (commutative) and matrix multiplication (associative), we can scale them on the left or on the right by some scalar, and we can form Kronecker products. **However**, I argue that only matrix addition and multiplication are meaningful, while scalar multiplication and Kronecker products are meaningless.

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are *right* $R$-modules, both free of finite rank, and we have chosen bases $(u_i)$ of $U$ and $(v_i)$ of $V$. Then a map of abelian groups  $\varphi \colon U \to V$ is called *$R$-linear* if $\varphi(u \lambda) = \varphi(u) \lambda$ for all $u \in U$ and $\lambda \in R$. An $R$-linear map $\varphi$ determines a matrix $[\varphi]_{i, j}$ with entries in $R$ in the usual way, where the coefficients are defined by the equation
$$ \varphi(v_j) = \sum_i u_i [\varphi]_{i, j}. $$
Addition of linear maps correpsonds to matrix addition, and composition of linear maps corresponds to matrix multiplication as usual. But scaling a linear map here is *undefined*, since the abelian group $\operatorname{Hom}_R(U, V)$ of $R$-linear maps between $U$ and $V$ is not an $R$-module in any way. One is *tempted* to define a left action of $R$ on the hom space by postcomposition by $(\lambda, \varphi) \mapsto 1_\lambda \circ \varphi$, where $1_\lambda \colon V \to V$ is the map which performs scalar multiplication by $\lambda$. However, in the noncommutative world the map $1_\lambda$ is no longer $R$-linear, and neither is the composition $1_\lambda \circ \varphi$.

This scaling problem is showing that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(U, V)$ is only an abelian group for noncommutative $R$, it is not an $R$-module, and so taking tensor products is not well-defined. (However, it *is* a module over the centre of $R$, so for example if $R$ is the quaternions then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(U, V)$ is a real vector space, and a tensor product could be taken over $\mathbb{R}$. I haven't worked out what operation this corresponds to on matrices).